# Using a local JSON file as a data source for an ASP.NET Core API?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm new to ASP.NET and am creating a simple API following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

The approach in the tutorial is to use `UseInMemoryDatabase`, this is working fine but I have a local JSON file with data that I would like to initialise the database with. On top of this, I would also like to keep this JSON file consistent with the in memory database, e.g. a POST to the API will also update the local JSON file with the added record.

My initial thought was to simply write the contents of the database to the JSON file after each operation, so for example

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Person>> PostPerson(Person person)
{
    _context.People.Add(person);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    // write _context.People to local JSON file

    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetPerson), new { id = person.Id }, person);
}
```

This would keep consistency between the local JSON file, and the in-memory database, but it seems untidy.

Comment: Just use a database like MySQL for example. It seems pretty much overhead to keep the file and the db in sync.

Comment: @jeb very true, out of curiosity though, is there an easier way to make this possible? Or is manually writing each CRUD operation to the JSON file when it's performed the only way to do this?

Comment: Sorry, no idea i never really tried to.